# 7A 125v fridge into a 15A 125v outlet?

Tags: receptacle, refrigerator, voltage, electric

My outlet reads 15A 125V, I bought a fridge with a plug that reads 7A 125V, and IH range who's plug reads 15A 100V. Is it safe to use these items?

I bought both an IH range and a fridge that said they are 50Hz/60Hz, so I assumed it was safe to use in my apartment. However, the plugs do not match the outlet.

Fridge plug = 7A 125V (the manual says the rated voltage is 100V)

IH range= 15A 100V

I've done as much reading about this as I can before asking for help, but quite frankly, I'm still afraid of accidentally burning down my apartment.

Backstory:
I recently moved to Japan and I cannot read the language very well yet (I can only read and speak enough to survive). To make matters worse, I have to buy my own living equipment (stove, fridge, etc.) and don't know much about electrical currents. What I do know is that the outlets in my prefecture is typically 60Hz.

If it helps (I doubt it), all of my supplies have been bought here.

Any and a help is greatly appreciated.
-Electrically Lost

Comment: Did you buy at a local store or online?  Have read that Japan uses 100 volts as their standard.  125 volts is more of a North American(standard voltage is 120).  Mis match plugs and outlets is very good clue something is not right.  Would find someone who does know Japanese and English well and at talk to landlord/electrician/store first.

Comment: The "7A" label on the fridge plug is the maximum amount of current which the fridge can ever 'draw' through that plug. the "15A" label on the outlet is the maximum amount of current which that outlet *can* safely supply - it's not the amount of current the outlet will 'try to push' into your fridge. So as long at they're physically compatible, then plug your fridge in without fear. I can't answer about the "100V" label on the range though..

Comment: When you wrote 'My outlet reads 15a 125V', did you mean it is marked/labeled as that or you took a meter reading and the meter said 125v?  If labelled then that is what the outlet is rated for, but can have less voltage if the power company only supplies 100v.  The market of Japen might be too small to make special 100v outlets, so they use the common 125v outlets.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your circuit breaker or fuse panel?

Comment: Japan uses parallel blade "Type A" (NEMA 1-15)  receptacles for their 100v circuits, if it is marked 125v the receptacle  was likely made to be compatible with North American NEMA 5-15 standards. A NEMA 1-15 (Type A) plug will fit into a 5-15 receptacle. In North America 5-15's are protected by 15 or 20A circuit breakers, and would expect using 22A on one of our circuits could trip a breaker. Without being familiar with circuit layout in Japan I would still expect a similar result.

Comment: If I’m the US, remember the 80% rule - maximum load (non-motor) on a breaker is 80% of its rating. If not, check your local code.